# Should the pendulum action on my Bosch jigsaw increase with higher settings?

Tags: wood, woodworking, cutting

I recently bought a brand new [Bosch GST 8000 E](https://www.bosch-professional.com/lb/en/products/gst-8000-e-060158H000) jigsaw and I think that it has a problem regarding the pendulum settings. I made 2 tests with it to see if the pendulum action is good.

The 1st test: I put the pendulum commutator to "0" and I saw that there is no pendulum action. Next, I moved the commutator to "1" and I saw the pendulum action. Next, I set the commutator to "2" but the pendulum action remained the same. Next, I set the commutator to "3" and I saw that the pendulum action remained the same with "1" and "2". So no more pendulum action on positions "2" and "3", in comparison with position "1" of the commutator.

The 2nd test: I took a piece of wood (about 20mm in thickness) and I tried to cut it with different pendulum settings. It took the same amount of time for the jigsaw to cut the piece of wood at all pendulum settings. 
The blade used is the T 144 D, made by Bosch.

Please explain if I am wrong when using the pendulum settings, or my jigsaw is defective ?

Comment: The claim is that there are four settings, so it's reasonable to expect that. Who knows if the intervals are linear, though. Are you sure your measurements are precise?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure your timing test is valid. That's a fairly thick board, so there's likely to be some amount of kickback, reducing the effect of the orbital action. Maybe try again with a thin board, though I'm not sure how you'll normalize force.

Comment: I don't know if the measurement of the pendulum actions are 100% precise. I looked at the blade with my bare eyes, so I think that if there was a very little increase of pendulum action when moving the commutator (from "1" to "2" for example), then probably I didn't saw it.

Comment: Normally I only notice a speed change having a larger swing would be of no value is there enough space to clear the debris? This will be the same distance at 10 strokes or 100 strokes per unit of time.